# In C, is the backslash character (\) required when one needs to split arguments of functions or logical conditions into multiple lines?

Tags: c, syntax, conditional-statements, arguments, backslash

I recently saw this snippet of code:

```
static HAL_StatusTypeDef Program_Flash_Page(uint32_t const page_address, \
  void* const pBufferData, uint32_t const nBufferSize) {

  uint32_t Address = page_address;
  uint64_t *DATA_64 = (uint64_t *) pBufferData;
  while (Address < (page_address + nBufferSize)) {

    if (HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_DOUBLEWORD, Address, *DATA_64) == \
      HAL_OK) {
      Address = Address + 8;
      DATA_64++;
    }
    else {
      return HAL_ERROR;
    }

  }

  return HAL_OK;

}
```

As you can see, backslashes were used to present a list of arguments and a logical condition in multiple lines.

As I learned from Kernighan and Ritchie (2nd edition, paragraph A.12.2, p.207), "lines that end with the backslash \ character are folded by deleting the backslash and the following newline character" during preprocessing.

What remained unclear to me is that if this syntax is obligatory or if one can just use a new line character (hit the enter button) while coding.

Comment: In your example the backslashes are completely useless. There is no problem if you have a line break in any statement. That only gets important if you define multi-line macros.

Comment: @Gerhardh True now, but there have likely been specific older C implementations that needed explicit line-continuation characters.  [Such line-continuation is still part of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2p1) so while useless today, they're still valid standard C.

Comment: @AndrewHenle if we see the `HAL_Flash..` function then we know that it is STM32. There are no "older" (ie requiring `\`) ARM Cortex target compilers. \

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I don't believe there was ever a C implementation which required line splicing. Indeed, I think it's more likely that there were prestandard C implementations which didn't implement line splicing. In the first edition of K&R, the text is clear that the only significance of newline characters and other whitespace is to separate tokens. The use of `\` followed by a newline was allowed only in two contexts: string literals and macro definitions. According to K&Rv2, line splicing anywhere was introduced during standardization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slashes are optional except for defining multi line macros as Gerhardh mentioned.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//valid macro
#define BAR(x, y, z) printf("%d %c %f\n", \
                            x, \
                            y, \
                            z);

//invalid macro, this won't compile if uncommented
/*
#define BAR(x, y, z) printf("%d %c %f\n",
x,
    y,
    z);
*/

void foo(int x, char y, float z) {
    printf("%d %c %f\n", x, y, z);
}

int main() {
    //valid
    foo(5, \
        'c', \
        0.0f);

    //also valid
    foo(5,
        'c',
        0.0f);

    //even use of the macro without slashes is valid
    BAR(5,
        'c',
        0.0f);

    return 0;
}
```